# trouble creating a continuous zoom in (android)

Tags: android, view, zooming

i am trying to write an Application for android that zooms in AFTER the user FINISHED dragging or touching the screen (this means at motionEvent.ACTION_UP).
i want it to be continuous just like in a pinch zoom, but the problem is that pinch zooming is a continuous action and therefore create many events , what i am looking for is a SINGLE event (motionEvent.Action_up) that will cause continuous zooming.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` you should set a timer which will repeatedly, and slowly, zoom over the designated area you decide (Instead of zooming according to future motion events, like in pinch zooming).